# Compare different time windows of data to get most similair in python

Tags: python

I got a dataset of sensor data from different devices. Sadly, the timestamps are not fitting together, so I need a different strategy to fit them.

For example: `dataset_1`:

```
timestamp         accelerometer x/y/z gyroscope x/y/z
1636364625.432132;(276, -1692, 1100);(-30, -24, 13)
1636364625.433018;(280, -1685, 1092);(-40, -35, 10)
1636364625.4402454;(299, -1707, 1086);(-80, -33, 19)
1636364625.4471848;(290, -1716, 1078);(-93, -36, 18)
1636364625.46067;(286, -1733, 1070);(-87, -46, 14)
1636364625.4831429;(287, -1745, 1073);(-60, -36, 22)
1636364625.5075622;(292, -1735, 1078);(-31, -28, 15)
1636364625.5285385;(278, -1729, 1064);(-38, -17, 16)
1636364625.544534;(281, -1722, 1059);(-40, -12, 11)
```

and `dataset_2`:

```
timestamp           accelerometer x/y/z            gyroscope x/y/z
1636364622.9333024;(1.050449, -0.973879, 9.875179);(14.0, -10.01, -3.22)
1636364622.9403024;(1.050449, -0.973879, 9.875179);(46.970001, -71.959999, -70.279999)
1636364622.9403024;(1.050449, -0.973879, 9.875179);(-52.150002, 9.8, -8.75)
1636364622.9413025;(1.160519, -1.040878, 10.028319);(-60.130001, 11.97, -7.28)
1636364622.9413025;(1.167697, -1.172483, 9.695717);(-75.389999, 14.7, -7.63)
1636364622.9563024;(1.335195, -1.548156, 9.566505);(-98.629997, 20.02, -7.7)
1636364622.9693024;(1.167697, -1.749153, 9.432507);(-119.209999, 28.139999, -9.17)
1636364622.9883025;(0.995414, -1.842474, 9.741181);(-134.889999, 31.780001, -11.76)
1636364623.0103025;(0.847059, -2.175076, 9.829715);(-157.289993, 35.0, -13.23)
```

What I can say is the following: The full timeframe of `dataset_1` is in `dataset_2`, but I don't know the correct time difference to calculate it back or just take the correct timeframe.

Therefore my idea consists of getting the whole timeframe (or values) of `dataset_1` (for eg with length 10) and searching inside `dataset_2` (for eg with length 30) and taking the timeframe where the values are the closest.

The data rows are similar, but not the same. How can I accomplish such a comparison?

Edit: Add example

What I mean is:

1. Select a window of len `dataset_1` for example 10
2. Slide through `dataset_2` line by line and compare the two windows.
3. Select the window of size `dataset_1` (10) where the most similarity between the lines is given.

Comment: As written your question is a bit confusing, could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish with an small example of the desired output.  Also, please include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: How do you define "most similarity" over 10 lines? What if one of them is an outlier? Do you want to consider a rolling average? Skip outliers?

Comment: Yeah something like that. As i said the datasets are similar and recorded at the same time. Therefore if the outlier is in dataset_1, it should also be in dataset_2 at the same point.

Another idea might be to use signal processing to get the start and end of the signals and just slice it out, but I don't have much knowledge in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at those numbers, it appears that, in addition to your timestamp issue, dataset_1 and dataset_2 have different units for the accelerometer and gyroscope readings.

I would do the following:

1. Split the accelerometer and gyroscope readings into 3 separate columns each.
2. Write a function call `get_correlations(dt)`. This function will first apply a time offset `dt` to the timestamps in dataset_1. For each line of dataset 1, get values from dataset 2 by linearly interpolating the timestamps on either side. Compute the correlation of the dataset_1 values with those from dataset_2. Output these 6 correlations.
3. Call `get_corrleation(dt)` for a range of`dt` values.
4. For each of the 6 columns, plot correlation against `dt`. I expect you will see a clear peak at the correct offset.

To help further, I would need to know what data structure you are starting from. Are these in pandas `DataFrame`s? How many rows in each dataset? Are the timestamps evenly spaced?

Comment: Yes, the data correlates, but is not the same. Dataset_1 has a scaling of 16 in gyro data and 2048 in accelerometer data. For dataset_2 the scalings are unknown. The data should be raw data from the devices, but I don't know if any internal scaling is applied (dataset_1 is from a Myo armband and dataset_2 is from a Samsung Gear S3 Frontier). Both datasets have the same frequency of 50 Hz.

Your thought is similar to mine. Even though the scalings could be different, the peaks and downs should be the same.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this on a static dataset, or realtime?

Comment: Static dataset... The data capture is done. I need to fit the data frames together.... Originally I wanted to use timestamp comparison, which would have been the easiest method, but since the timestamps don't fit and I don't know the offset on the start and end of dataset_2, I need to come up with a different solution.